# Best practice for delimiters within HTTP URL path

Tags: api, http, url, uri, urlencode

Would it be unwise to use various punctuation characters in an HTTP URL path? I am in the process of defining resource URLs for an API. These resource URLs will have to be accessed, stored, and transmitted by a wide variety of clients and middleware, so it is important that they do not contain characters that are likely to cause issues.

[RFC 3986, section 2.2. "Reserved Characters"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) specifies the following characters as sub-delims: !$&'()*+,;=

Are any of these illegal for arbitrary use within URL paths in the HTTP scheme?

Even if they are legal according to the standards, do any of these have a high chance of causing real-world interoperability problems due to non-compliant software?

Are there any specific sub-delims that you have previously used without issue in a widely-deployed API (this would provide evidence that the ones you used are safe)?

The motivation is that we need to delimit key-value pairs which do not have hierarchical semantics. We are considering doing this: http://doriantaylor.com/policy/http-url-path-parameter-syntax . However, if this is likely to be a problem, we will just do http://example.com/key1/value1/key2/value2

thanks

Comment: I would go with Dorian Taylor's schema until something breaks, and then add `/key/value/key/value` as an _alternative_ but keep the old one working for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever way you go, be sure of it; changing APIs can be problematic, even with a version specified.  It's a **bad idea** to have multiple locations for the same resource - there should be **one** canonical location.  While in theory you can use a HTTP 301 redirect, if you are concerned about compatibility it's best avoided.

The Dorian Taylor set scheme looks sensible (and completely legal) and should not give any compatibility issues with any system (or any that isn't hugely buggy).

If your URL needs to be used as a parameter in a new URL the forward slash and equals will have to be [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), but that's true for both a standard query string (`?&=`) and your proposed alternative, as well as the `://` if the protocol is included.  Obviously, if you want to use `;,=` in your values you will need to encode them.

The only possible issue I can see is if your URLs are stored in a CSV, but CSV libraries are common and quoting special characters is well defined.